# Adding 1 bar delay (pine script)

Tags: pine-script

I want the conditions "buyDB" and "sellDB" to trigger 1 bar *after* the bar of the close, ie. 1 bar after the crossover/crossunder. What would I add to this script for that? Thanks in advance!:

```
buyDB = crossover(close, TopBox)
sellDB = crossunder(close, BottomBox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a historical operator on your condition. eg.

buyDB = (crossover(close, TopBox))[1]
sellDB = (crossunder(close, BottomBox)[1]

or you could add it in later if you have other conditions:

long = condition and buyDB[1]

Cheers and best of luck with your trading and coding!

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work as that would theoretically make the condition 1 bar earlier and I need it 1 bar later. I wish there was a replacement for [1] that would count future bars instead of previous bars.

Comment: That statement would become true one bar after the cross…

Comment: Theoretically yes, but for some reason it's not quite working with this particular study. I'll tinker around with it. Thanks!